# Async requests in guzzlephp (or php-ga-measurement-protocol)

Tags: php, google-analytics, sendasynchronousrequest, guzzle

Does anyone know how to send a working and non-blocking async request using guzzlephp?

There seems to be a support for this but it does not seem to be implemented

```
<?php

$this->guzzle->requestAsync('post', 'http://', ['synchronous' => false])->wait();

?>
```

Implemented in a sense that it does not wait for the response.

There is also a problem with php-ga-measurement-protocol

```
$analytics->setAsyncRequest(true)->sendPageview();
```

Answer (score 0):

What problem you are talking about?

Async requests work fine in Guzzle, exactly as you described. You just get a promise from `requestAsync()` immediately, do other stuff and take the response, when you are ready.

```
// ['synchronous' => false] is not required.
$responsePromise = $this->guzzle->requestAsync('post', 'http://...');

// Your stuff...

$response = $responsePromise->wait();
```

Don't know about php-ga-measurement-protocol, BTW, but seems that this lib implements them correctly too.